# How to add empty (0) coordinates into a partially filled data.frame for a given range?

Tags: r, data-structures, data.table

I am not totally sure how to describe my problem, so I might just need help to find the right keywords to search for.

Here are some dummy data that resembles my own data, there are `x` and `y` co-ordinates and a `z` value:

```
require(data.table)
example <- data.table(x = c(-3, -4, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4, 5),
                      y = c(2, -2, -2, -3, -0, 3, 4, 4, -1, 4, 4, 4),
                      z = c(10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 70, 70, 80, 90, 90))
```

There are some duplicate co-ordinates in there, e.g. at `(4,4)` so the next step is to average the `z` values for the duplicate points:

```
example <- as.data.table(aggregate(z ~ x + y, data = example, FUN = "mean"))
```

Next, I would like to add `z = 0` values to all of the coordinates that I don't have data for, e.g. `(x = 0, y = 0)`, `(x = 1, y = 1)` etc. for the range `-5:5` in both `x` and `y` axes.

How do I go about this?

To clarify: I have `z` values for specific `x` and `y` coordinates, I'd like to create a data table (or matrix) which  has all `x,y` coordinates from `-5,-5` to `5,5` with `z = 0` except for the specific `z` values I already have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
example[, .(z=mean(z)), by=.(x, y)][CJ(x=-5:5, y=-5:5), on=c("x", "y")][is.na(z), z:=0][]
      x  y  z
  1: -5 -5  0
  2: -5 -4  0
  3: -5 -3  0
  4: -5 -2  0
  5: -5 -1  0
 ---         
117:  5  1  0
118:  5  2  0
119:  5  3  0
120:  5  4 90
121:  5  5  0
```

Here, `example[, .(z=mean(z)), by=.(x, y)]` performs the `data.table` equivalent of your `aggregate` function. The result is then joined to the Cartesian product of -5:5 with itself (11^2 = 121 observations) `CJ(x=-5:5, y=-5:5)` with the second chain `[CJ(x=-5:5, y=-5:5), on=c("x", "y")]`. The join fills in NA for x y combinations not present in the aggregated data, so in the final chain, The `NA` values of z are set to 0 `[is.na(z), z:=0]`. The last bit prints the output.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do - thank you so much! I don't fully understand each step, but the result is what I'm trying to achieve, so i'll study each section of your solution. Thank you again!

Comment: It is worth reading (and re-reading) the vignettes on their [Github site](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: You can do `example[CJ(x=-5:5, y=-5:5), on=c("x", "y"), if (.N == 0L) 0 else mean(z), by=.EACHI]`

Comment: Thanks, @Frank. I've been meaning to learn how to use `.EACHI` for a while now. This example should help.